# Find (or calculate) log-likelihood value, AIC, and BIC for SUR model (for each equation) with systemfit

Tags: r, aic, bic, likelihood, seemingly-unrelated-regressions

I have estimated `SUR` model with `systemfit` (R package). With the estimated results, I am trying to get logLik, AIC and BIC for each of SUR model. For the whole logLik, I can just use `logLik` function. However, how can I get the goodness-of-fit (logLik, AIC, and BIC) for each equation of SUR model?

Here is a sample of SUR estimation with `systemfit`.

```
data( "Kmenta" )
eqDemand <- consump ~ price + income
eqSupply <- consump ~ price + farmPrice + trend
system <- list( demand = eqDemand, supply = eqSupply )

fitsur <- systemfit( system, "SUR", data = Kmenta )    
logLik( fitsur )
```

How can I get the `logLik`, AIC and BIC for each equation (`eqDemand`,`eqSupply`)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how I would proceed, inspired by, e.g., [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/73196/recalculate-log-likelihood-from-a-simple-r-lm-model) and [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/87345/calculating-aic-by-hand-in-r) thread. In principle, one could of course consider other likelihoods than the normal, but there seems to be no good reason to do so here.

```
eq2 <- summary(fitsur$eq[[2]])                              
n <- eq2$df[1] + eq2$df[2]                                  # get sample size
sigma.sq.hat.MLE <- eq2$ssr/n                               # the MLE of the error variance 
logLiK.eq2 <- -n/2*(log(2*pi) + 1 + log(sigma.sq.hat.MLE))  # the log-likelihood
p <- eq2$df[1] + 1                                          # the number of parameters, including the error variance
aic.eq2 <- -2*logLiK.eq2 + 2*p                              # definition of AIC
```

The generalization to BIC should be obvious, and surely also how to get equation 1.

The reasoning underlying the above calculations is that the likelihood of such a system of equations is [matrix normal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_normal_distribution) with, at the MLE, means equal to the fitted values and column-covariance matrix equal to the covariance matrix of the residuals across equations, say, $V$. Equivalently, the likelihood then is [multivariate normal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_normal_distribution#Marginal_distributions), where the observations belonging to equation $i$ are normal with variance $V_{ii}I_n$, thanks to the properties of marginal distributions of multivariate normals.

To illustrate the point about the matrix normal, let us compare that log-likelihood to `logLik`. I generate a somewhat larger dataset, as the small Kmenta dataset leads to small discrepancies I haven't traced back:

```
library(systemfit)
library(LaplacesDemon)

n <- 1e3  # be careful with larger n - dmatrixnorm takes a long time!!
y1 <- rnorm(n)
y2 <- rnorm(n)
x <- rnorm(n)

eq1 <- y1 ~ x
eq2 <- y2 ~ x
system <- list(eq1, eq2)

fitsur <- systemfit(system, "SUR")    
M <- cbind(fitted(fitsur$eq[[1]]), fitted(fitsur$eq[[2]]))
U <- diag(n)
V <- fitsur$residCov

> dmatrixnorm(cbind(y1,y2), M, U, V, log=T) 
[1] -2848.044

> logLik(fitsur)
'log Lik.' -2848.042 (df=7)
```

Comment: I just checked your code. Sorry for the late feedback.Your answer is the exactly same as I did before. My concern was the correlation between equations. With the function 'logLik' from the 'systemfit' package, we can get the log-likelihood for the whole equation. Do you think logLik(fitsur) =  logLiK.eq2 + logLiK.eq1?

Comment: @Johnlegend, I spell out my reasoning in mroe detail - I am not so sure about the additive part, though.